# HTML_CSS_Media_query_not_working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media

Need help
I printed the document as a comp pdf file, but I can't see the lines in the table.

I searched the Internet and tried to find a way, but nothing worked. Is there a good way because it's only in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Hi, we'll need more info to help with this - what document, what media query, what is the outcome and are you saying it works OK on other browsers (which ones?) but not on IE11?  This should help you [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. We can't test without the code. Please clarify more clearly about the issue, in which browser it works and in which browser it doesn't work. You can also provide some screenshots to show the difference.